# jQuery/Javascript sliding toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement, var

I'm trying to make a sidebar that when clicked it (aside li) slides down the section paragraph (section p) with the same class.

```
var $asideGet = $('aside li').click(function(){
                $(this).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('class');
            });
        });




        var $sectionGet = $('section p').click(function(){
            $(this).each(function(){
            $(this).attr('class');
        });
    });
    if($asideGet == $sectionGet){
        $asideGet.click(function(){
            $sectionGet.slideToggle();
        });
    };
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: To solve this problem. It gets each aside li and section p correctly, but when I try to make and if statement, that when both are the same class, to show/slide down the section p.

Answer (score 0):

I reviwed the code and got something like this:
Oops... But when I click the aside li, it slides down all the section p, and I just want to slide down the section p with the same class as aside li does.

```
var $sectionP = $('section p');
    $sectionP.hide();



    var $asideLi = $('aside li');


function comparing(){
        $asideLi.click(function(){
            $(this).each(function(){
                var $asideClass = $(this).attr('class');
                    if($sectionP.hasClass($asideClass)){
                        $sectionP.slideToggle();
                    };
        }); //each function
    }); //click function


};
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: I still don't know how use this site, I created this account yesterday, that's why I posted an answer instead of editing my question!!!

Comment: No worries, This is why they allow you to make changes :)